# ASP.NET session gets null unexpectly

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a simple scenario. in one page of asp.net, I store a some values in session like

session("var") = "some string"
or 
session("var1") = object of generic list of string

and then use response.redirect to goto another page. 
on other page it shows things fine, but when we press a button to do an action on it, session gets null.

Remember, it doesn't always happen. Just sometimes it does so and other times it works fine. We do this practice a lot to move some values from page to page (by storing them into session and goto other page). We have very big application and all works fine, but from some days, have been having this issue on some sites with some users. Once again, it doesn't always happen. 99% it works fine but few times, we have this issue where session variable is no longer available.

Is there any way to know what is going wrong and where? We do store some other variables in the session as well, they seems fine at that time. only some of the session variables lose their values.

From my research, it seems people blames on the IIS worker process restart or Application Pool recycle. But I believe in such case all the session variables in the application must be voided, not selected few. Right?

also, is there any way to know in code if the pool or worker process was restarted?

thanks
Sameers

Comment: show some code for help

Comment: default time of session is 20 minute if you make a postback after 20 minutes it gets null automatically

Comment: What does "session gets null" mean? Does it mean that the session object itself is null, or that no value is stored for a particular key?

Comment: "but when we press a button to do an action on it, session gets null" - make sure you don't reset that particular session variable values conditionally somewhere.

Comment: Hey thanks for all your comments. Yes, I am aware of these scenarios already like update session variable somewhere else by mistake or such other things. I guarantee it is NOT happening anywhere. when I say null, that means, session("xvariable") is null or nothing. its just weird that I just redirected user under same domain under sale folder. For example, user selected few products to delete and I have a confirmation page. on the confirmation page, the selected product Ids (stored in session) are no longer available (its null or nothing). That is weird,user just selected them and now its gone

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're passing domain boundaries. Session is identified by a client cookie, which are usually stored on a per-domain basis. So, for example, a redirect from `www.whatever.com` to `client.whatever.com` will cause you to lose the session ID, which will appear to you as "voiding the session". So, be careful about sub-domains too. Going from `whatever.com` to `www.whatever.com` is fine, but the other way round, nope.

And yes, unless you're on a web farm IIS, restarting the worker process will kill all the sessions. Unless you store them in a database or something.

Comment: In case of subdomains the setting `httpCookies` configuration in web.config (system.web) would help. You can set the domain for which the session cookie will be valid. `domain=".stackoverflow.com"` would make the session available for subdomains of stackoverflow, too.